# one link for ios and android firebase dynamic links

Tags: react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I have my firebase dynamic links working for iOS, now have rewritten my app in react-native.

So is there a way to have a dynamic link that routes the user according to iOS / android?

Or should I have 2 separate links?

[image: firebase dynamic links]